# Backbone.js On Trigger Callback Binding Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone Collection that needs to fetch whenever another Backbone Model (no part of the Collection) changes.

When I write it like this:

```
this.fModel = new FooModel();
this.bCollection = new BarCollection();
this.fModel.on("change", this.bCollection.fetch, this)
```

I get the following error when the change event is triggered:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'trigger'
```

However, when I simply wrap the Collection's fetch call, it works as expected:

```
this.fModel = new FooModel();
this.bCollection = new BarCollection();
this.testfunc = function(){
    this.bCollection.fetch();
}
this.fModel.on("change", this.testfunc, this)
```

Why is this the case? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a fun one to try and explain :)

So when you call `on` like this:

```
this.fModel.on('change', this.bCollection.fetch, this);
```

You are setting the context that `fetch` is run in to whatever `this` is. In this code it looks like `this` is simply your top-level application or similar. `fetch` can't do much with that! Let's look at the implementation of `fetch`:

```
// Fetch the default set of models for this collection, resetting the
// collection when they arrive. If `add: true` is passed, appends the
// models to the collection instead of resetting.
fetch: function(options) {
  options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};
  if (options.parse === undefined) options.parse = true;
  var collection = this;
  var success = options.success;
  options.success = function(resp, status, xhr) {
    collection[options.add ? 'add' : 'reset'](collection.parse(resp, xhr), options);
    if (success) success(collection, resp);
  };
  options.error = Backbone.wrapError(options.error, collection, options);
  return (this.sync || Backbone.sync).call(this, 'read', this, options);
},
```

So we basically make it up to `var collection = this;`... *Oops!*

We've set `collection` inside `fetch` to be your top-level application!

---

So the reason it works when you wrap it is even more fun:

```
var wrapped = function() { this.bCollection.fetch(); };
this.fModel.on('change', wrapped, this);
```

We've set the context of `wrapped` to be `this`. That's fine because `this.bCollection` is exactly what we want. But when you call `fetch` on `bCollection` here, it's doing it in the normal way, binding `this` inside it to the object it was called on - this is normal javascript stuff now.

---

So, here's a TL;DR:

You actually want:

```
this.fModel.on('change', this.bCollection.fetch, this.bCollection);
```

Because the context of the `fetch` function call should be the collection itself, and nothing else.

Make sense?

Cheers :)